# Writing to excel skips a column Generic LDAP Query --

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, ldap

I'm currently writing an application to pull dynamic attributes from Active directory using DirectorySearcher. Everything pulls perfectly fine and I get the values however, I'm having a problem when writing to a datatable / excel, it's skipping in the second row and not lining up properly.

```
foreach (SearchResult sr in results)
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();

    for (var i = 0; i < ADProperties().Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        var j = ADProperties()[i];

        if (entry.Properties[j].Count > 0)
        {
            dr[j] = entry.Properties[j].Value.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        else
        {
            dr[j] = "Null";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: See how it's skipping a cell in the 2nd row.]

How do I make it line up properly?

Comment: If I understand that code correctly, you add a new row for each column you write to the DataTable or file.

Comment: Correct, so for each object in a List "ADProperties" create a new row.

Comment: Well, then the solution should be simple: Only add a new row when you really want to write a new row. :) Sorry that I can't be more helpful than that, but it's a bit hard to correct the code without any testdata.